# How to addition two value in list of list

Tags: python

can someone explain to me how i can addition two value in list of list ?

Here my list of list :

```
data =  [
   ["Autofollow", 7200, "00:00:00:00", "Name Of File0", "28/07/2021"],  # Line 1
   ["Autofollow", 300 , "00:00:00:00", "Name Of File2", "28/07/2021"],  # Line 2
   ["Autofollow", 3600, "00:00:00:00", "Name Of file3", "28/07/2021"],  # Line 3
       ]
```

here i generate randomly data :

```
i = 0
while i <= 2 :
    dataRand += random.choices(data)
    i += 1
```

I call the function totalInSecond with list dataRand :

```
 print(totalInSecod(dataRand))
```

here the function which must add the values ​​of value[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQzPF.png) :

```
def totalInSecod(someRandomData) :
    global sumDurationInSecond
    print(someRandomData)
    for value in someRandomData :
        sumDurationInSecond += value[1]
        return sumDurationInSecond
```

but the result does not add all the values ​​of my list of list..

I have this result :

```
[['Autofollow', 3600, '00:00:00:00', 'Name Of file3', '28/07/2021'], ['Autofollow', 7200, '00:00:00:00', 'Name Of File0', '28/07/2021']]
3600
```

**I would like to have 3600 + 7200 = 10800**

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked, but I can't find an answer

Comment: Your `print` statement is indented too far.  Scoot it out so it runs AFTER the `for`.  You are computing what you want, you're just not displaying it.  BTW, why is that a global?

Comment: What exactly is it that you wish to achieve? What is your desired output and what is the actual output of this code?

Comment: Edit the question to show us the output of this code, and explain why it isn't what you want.  Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Which 2 value? first and last one?

Comment: the value[1] of each list (here 3600 and 7200)

Comment: After editing, I see that the `return` statement is inside the for loop, so the loop will only execute once...

Comment: Oh wow realy... is just the return statement...

Comment: Then why didn't you add 300 from list 2? Isn't it should be (7200+300+3600)?

Comment: Use: `sum([d[1] for d in data])` if you want the sum of all values in the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i can presume, you want sum of all the elements at index 1

when you look at "sumDurationInSecond += value[1]"

you’ve tried to iterate over an object that is not iterable. if you want to use for loop here, you have to use it using range to grab list's elements.

for example -

```
def totalInSecod(someRandomData):
sumDurationInSecond = 0
for value in range(len(someRandomData)):
    sumDurationInSecond+=(someRandomData[value][1])
print(sumDurationInSecond)
```

other solution is to append the elements in a list and then return the sum of that list

```
 def totalInSecod(someRandomData):
 sumDurationInSecond = []
 for value in someRandomData:
    sumDurationInSecond.append(value[1])
 print(sum(sumDurationInSecond))
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is absolutely ok. You just have to return the after for loop.

**Your Code:**

```py
def totalInSecod(someRandomData) :
    sumDurationInSecond = 0
    for value in someRandomData :
        sumDurationInSecond += value[1]
    return sumDurationInSecond

data =  [
   ["Autofollow", 7200, "00:00:00:00", "Name Of File0", "28/07/2021"],  # Line 1
   ["Autofollow", 300 , "00:00:00:00", "Name Of File2", "28/07/2021"],  # Line 2
   ["Autofollow", 3600, "00:00:00:00", "Name Of file3", "28/07/2021"],  # Line 3
       ]
print(totalInSecod(data))
```

#### OR One Liner

```py
def totalInSecod(someRandomData):
    return sum(list(zip(*someRandomData))[1])

data =  [
   ["Autofollow", 7200, "00:00:00:00", "Name Of File0", "28/07/2021"],  # Line 1
   ["Autofollow", 300 , "00:00:00:00", "Name Of File2", "28/07/2021"],  # Line 2
   ["Autofollow", 3600, "00:00:00:00", "Name Of file3", "28/07/2021"],  # Line 3
       ]
print(totalInSecod(data))
```

**Output: 11100**